# How to Run a Wad file like doom with OpenGl

Tags: opengl

Hey I need A code example that allows me to run a wad file in OpenGL support.

```
// oPENGL.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//JOHN NAN

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GL\freeglut.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // Set up some memory buffers for our display
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    // Set the window size
    glutInitWindowSize(2560, 1080);
    // Create the window with the title "Hello,GL"
    glutCreateWindow("MT3d");
    // Bind the two functions (above) to respond when necessary
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    // Very important!  This initializes the entry points in the OpenGL driver so we can 
    // call all the functions in the API.
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
        return 1;
    }


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only way to run a Doom WAD file is to run Doom. And you will not get the full code for Doom here; go look it up yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "run"? If you mean to execute the Doom's WAD file then you just cannot. The WAD file is not an executable format, instead it's a structured file format containing textures, level geometry, etc. So instead of trying to "run" it you should read the WAD file and load all the data that it contains, and use it to generate valid data that can be fed into OpenGL. Take a look here for the WAD file format: [Zdoom Wiki](https://zdoom.org/wiki/WAD)

Comment: Well how do you run a exe in opengl with my program above or can you even do that

Comment: @JohnNay You cannot run an exe with OpenGL. OpenGL is just a rendering library for creating images on screen. Your program should instead read the data contained in the wad file and render it using OpenGL. A popular port of Doom that uses OpenGL is GZDoom. Take a look at it's source code: https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom?files=1

Comment: Hey do you know which files that I should look at for this question of mine in this https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom?files=1

Comment: @JohnNay For windows the entry point is in "src/win32/i_main.cpp". You can start from there, although many things may look strange to you. I recommend you to read a book on OpenGL and also on C++ and also learn to read binary data from files. This will help a lot